# I cannot change the name properly with my line name in fnc

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want to change my line name when ı call the different line in my test function but i cant.
For example,in a 1st print in test fnc,result is

**"<lineofthe.myLine object at 0x000002611E3EF370>properties:"**

but ı only need for test(line1) **" Line 1 properties: "** like this.

This is my code:

```
from lineofthe import myLine
        line1 = myLine() 
        line2 = myLine(2.7,-0.5,6.25,3)
        def test(lines_):
            print(f'{lines_}properties: ')      
            return
        test(line1)
        test(line2)
```

Thank you for your helps

Comment: You would need to store the line number in myLine class (provide it in the constructor). Then, you need to implement the special method `__str__` in myLine.

Comment: I'm a beginner in python.Could you write the full code please?

Comment: Post the code of myLine class.